# Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date + The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
create table pilot (
emp_num int,
pl_license varchar (3),
pl_ratings varchar (30),
pl_med_type int,
pl_med_date date,
pl_pt135_date date,
constraint PK_pilot primary key (emp_num)
)

insert into pilot(emp_num,pl_license,pl_ratings,pl_med_type,pl_med_date,pl_pt135_date)
values (101,'ATP','SEL/MEL/instr/CFII',1,12-4-2005,15-6-2005)
insert into pilot(emp_num,pl_license,pl_ratings,pl_med_type,pl_med_date,pl_pt135_date)
values (104,'ATP','SEL/MEL/instr',1,10-5-2005,23-3-2006)
insert into pilot(emp_num,pl_license,pl_ratings,pl_med_type,pl_med_date,pl_pt135_date)
values (105,'COM','SEL/MEL/instr/CFI',2,25-2-2006,12-2-2005)
insert into pilot(emp_num,pl_license,pl_ratings,pl_med_type,pl_med_date,pl_pt135_date)
values (106,'COM','SEL/MEL/instr',2,02-4-2006,24-12-2005)
insert into pilot(emp_num,pl_license,pl_ratings,pl_med_type,pl_med_date,pl_pt135_date)
      values (109,'COM','SEL/MEL/instr/CFII',1,14-4-2006,21-4-2006)
```

My question is there is an error in every insert

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

How to fix this?

---

Also here ...

```
create table employee (
emp_num int,
constraint PK_employee primary key (emp_num),
foreign key(emp_num) references pilot(emp_num),
emp_title varchar (4),
emp_lname varchar (20),
emp_fname varchar (30),
emp_initial varchar (2),
emp_dob date,
emp_hire_date date, 
)
insert into employee(emp_num,emp_title,emp_lname,emp_fname,emp_initial,emp_dob,emp_hire_date)
values (100,'Mr.','Kolmycz','George','D',15-5-1942,15-3-1987)
insert into employee(emp_num,emp_title,emp_lname,emp_fname,emp_initial,emp_dob,emp_hire_date)
values (101,'Ms.','Lewis','Rhonda','G',19-3-1965,25-4-1988)
insert into employee(emp_num,emp_title,emp_lname,emp_fname,emp_initial,emp_dob,emp_hire_date)
values (102,'Mr.','Vandam','Rhett',' ',14-11-1958,20-12-1992)
insert into employee(emp_num,emp_title,emp_lname,emp_fname,emp_initial,emp_dob,emp_hire_date)
values (103,'Ms.','Jones','Anne','M',16-10-1974,28-8-2005)
insert into employee(emp_num,emp_title,emp_lname,emp_fname,emp_initial,emp_dob,emp_hire_date)
values (104,'Mr.','Lange','John','P',08-11-1971,20-10-1996)
insert into employee(emp_num,emp_title,emp_lname,emp_fname,emp_initial,emp_dob,emp_hire_date)
values (105,'Mr.','williams','Robert','D',14-3-1975,08-1-2006)
insert into employee(emp_num,emp_title,emp_lname,emp_fname,emp_initial,emp_dob,emp_hire_date)
values (106,'Mrs.','Duzak','Jeanine','K',12-2-1968,05-1-1991)
insert into employee(emp_num,emp_title,emp_lname,emp_fname,emp_initial,emp_dob,emp_hire_date)
values (107,'Mr.','Diante','Jorge','D',21-8-1974,05-1-1991)
insert into employee(emp_num,emp_title,emp_lname,emp_fname,emp_initial,emp_dob,emp_hire_date)
values (108,'Mr.','Wlesenbach','Paul','R',14-2-1966,18-11-1994)
insert into employee(emp_num,emp_title,emp_lname,emp_fname,emp_initial,emp_dob,emp_hire_date)
values (109,'Ms.','Travis','Elizabeth','K',18-6-1961,14-4-1991)
insert into employee(emp_num,emp_title,emp_lname,emp_fname,emp_initial,emp_dob,emp_hire_date)
values (110,'Mrs.','Genkazi','Leighla','W',19-5-1970,01-12-1992)
```

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__crew__emp_num__0F975522". The conflict occurred in database "melisa", table "dbo.employee", column 'emp_num'. error on
>   this table

```
create table earndrating(
emp_num int,
constraint PK_earndarating primary key(emp_num, rtg_code),
rtg_code varchar(6),
foreign key (emp_num) references pilot(emp_num),
foreign key(rtg_code) references rating(rtg_code),
earningth_date varchar(20),
)
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(101,'CFI','18-Feb-98' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(101,'CFII','14-Dec-05' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(101,'INSTR','08-Nov-93' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(101,'MEL','23-Jun-94' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(101,'SEL','21-Apr-93' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(104,'INSTR','14-Jul-96' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(104,'MEL','29-Jan-97' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(104,'SEL','12-Mar-95' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(105,'CFI','18-Nov-97' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(105,'INSTR','17-Apr-95' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(105,'MEL','12-Aug-95' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(105,'SEL','23-Sep-94' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(106,'INSTR','20-Dec-95' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(106,'MEL','02-Apr-95' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(105,'SEL','10-Mar-94' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(109,'CFI','05-Nov-98' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(109,'CFII','21-Jun-03' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(109,'INSTR','23-Jul-96' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(109,'MEL','15-Marc-97' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(109,'SEL','05-Feb-96' )
    insert into earndrating(emp_num,rtg_code,earningth_date)
    values(109,'SES','12-May-96' )
```

Comment: Your problem has now changed.  Initially it was your formatting of the date string, now it's a foreign key constraint.  In the latter case, this means that you are inserting values into `earndrating.emp_num` that do not exist in `pilot.emp_num`.

Comment: Not sure why this got down voted so many times. This Q&A helped me out.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This expression `12-4-2005` is a calculated int and the value is `-1997`. You should do like this instead `'2005-04-12'` with the `'` before and after.

Comment: it does not work, theres a new error saying insert into Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @Jeo Talavera: try using the **ISO-8601** format! Use '20050412' for your date - `YYYYMMDD` - that works regardless of your SQL Server language and regional settings....

Comment: @Jeo Talavera - did you wrap with `'` **and** changed to `yyyy-mm-dd` ?

Comment: Actually with `DATE` (unlike `DATETIME`/`SMALLDATETIME`), yyyy-mm-dd will work regardless of language / regional settings.

Answer (score 7):

Try wrapping your dates in single quotes, like this:

```
'15-6-2005'
```

It should be able to parse the date this way.

Comment: it does not work, theres a new error saying  insert into Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @Jeo Talavera: You have several insert statements in your example. Isn't this error from the next insert statement? Apply the answer above to all date fields in all the inserts.

Comment: Why would you suggest dd-m-yyyy? It should be yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: I didn't suggest it. That was his code. I figured he might be British, so I left it alone ;) I just wrapped it in quotes.

Comment: @Jeo the point is that you should use a SAFE format because your unsafe mm-dd-yyyy format may not work on another server or for another user. Try `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH; DECLARE @d DATE = '06-15-2011';`

Answer (score 6):

FYI this turned out to be an issue for me where I had two tables in a statement like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
```

It worked, but then somewhere along the line the order of columns in one of the table definitions got changed.  Changing the `*` to `SELECT column1, column2` fixed the issue.  No idea how that happened, but lesson learned!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tried 'yyyy-mm-dd' format i.e. '2013-26-11' and got rid of this problem...

Comment: 'yyyy-mm-dd' <> '2013-26-11' :)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEINFO VALUES
(1, 'Sanjay',   'Mehra',    'HR',       'P1',   'Hyderabad(HYD)',   '01/12/1976',   'M'),
(2, 'Ananya',   'Mishra',   'Admin',    'P2',   'Delhi(DEL)',      '02/05/1968',    'F'),
(3, 'Rohan',    'Diwan',    'Account',  'P3',   'Mumbai(BOM)',     '01/01/1980',    'M'),
(4, 'Sonia',    'Kulkarni',   'HR',     'P1',   'Hyderabad(Hyd)',   '02/05/1992',    'F'),
(5, 'Ankit',    'Kapoor',   'Admin',    'P2',   'Delhi(DEL)',        '03/07/1994', 'M');
```

if you are getting this *[Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date]*
error then just add your dates in single qoutes ''.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

the format is ('MM-DD-YYYY') for the date

Answer (score -1):

Just on this, if you have null values it also converts it to an int

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).