# SQL Server 2008 Query to Calculate Total Time Between Successive Events

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to be able to calculate the total time between certain events in SQL Server 2008.

I have a table as follows:

```
UserId   Event      EventTimestamp
+-------+----------+---------------+
 1       CheckedIn  14-05-15 10:01
 2       CheckedIn  14-05-15 10:15
 3       CheckedIn  14-05-15 10:17
 1       CheckedOut 14-05-15 10:25
 1       Logout     14-05-15 10:26
```

If you take a look at the table, a user can check-in, then can check-out and then go offline.

I want to calculate the time between a person checking-in to the point they check-out grouped by each week where the duration (between check-in and check-out) is less than 10 minutes.

So far I've managed to group by week, but I can't seem to calculate the duration between those events (which will happen in that order)...

```
select      
   'Week ' + cast(datepart(wk, EventUpdateStamp) as varchar(2)) Week,     
    UserId,
    Event 
from MyTable 
group by datepart(wk, EventUpdateStamp), UserId, Event
```

I would like to have the results like this:

```
UserId   TotalSessionCheckInTimeMinutes  WeekNumber   
+-------+------------------------------+---------------+
 1       24                             43
```

Taking the first row as an example:

- 1 is the User's ID
- 24 is the total duration in minutes between his
  check-in and check-out
- 43 is the week number in the year

I only want to include check-in to check-out. Don't want to measure between check out and logout (in other words, measure how long he was checked-in for).

Comment: can you explain your result this row: 1   10     43?. 10 mean 10:00?

Comment: SQL Server version 2008 R2

Comment: 1 10 43: 1 is the User's ID, 24 is the total duration in minutes between his check-in and check-out, 43 is the week number in the year.

Comment: @AshesToAshes: I think the second rows must be: 1 1 43 (where 1 is User ID, 1 is difference bewtween Checked Out and Logout, 43 number of week). Right?

Comment: we only want to include check-in to check-out, so exclude the 1 1 20 result as we dont want to measure between check out and logout. (meaning how long he was in the office)

Comment: I've updated my answer with Logout remove

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.UserId, 
    DATEDIFF(minute,
        t1.EventTimestamp,
        (SELECT MIN(t3.EventTimestamp)
        FROM MyTable t3
        WHERE t3.UserId = t1.UserId
        AND t3.EventTimestamp> t1.EventTimestamp)
    ), 
   CAST(DATEPART(wk, EventTimestamp) as varchar(2)) Week
FROM MyTable t1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 'NEXT'
    FROM MyTable t2
   WHERE t2.UserId = t1.UserId
   AND t2.EventTimestamp> t1.EventTimestamp
   AND t2.Event != 'Logout')
```

**SqlFiddle**

Go [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19992/4/0)

Comment: It gave an error saying it doesn't know what 't' is. When I change t.UserId to t1.UserId, I get results but they are all negative values. Also, I noticed you are not comparing against the Event?

Comment: fixed. t.UserId -> t1.UserId (I try on Sql Fiddle but today is down)

Comment: Yes I'm failing to get it working on SQL Fiddle but it also is not working for me :(

Comment: I've tried on my PC. The result is: 1 24 20 / 1 1 20

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood you in your previous comment, we only want to include check-in to check-out, so exclude the 1 1 20 result as we dont want to measure between check out and logout. (meaning how long he was in the office).

Comment: To exclude, do I extend your where clause to say and t2.Event != 'Logout' ?

Comment: Yes, in the subquery exclude the event as follow t2.event != 'Logout'

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.UserId, DATEPART(HOUR,A.TotalSessionCheckInTimeMinutes)*60 + DATEPART(MINUTE,A.TotalSessionCheckInTimeMinutes) AS TotalSessionCheckInTimeMinutes, DATEPART(WEEKDAY, M.EventTimestamp) FROM Mytable M
     CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT CAST((M1.EventTimestamp - M2.EventTimestamp) AS TIME) AS TotalSessionCheckInTimeMinutes
        FROM Mytable M1
          CROSS JOIN Mytable M2
            WHERE M1.Event = 'CheckOut' AND M2.Event = 'CheckIn' AND M1.UserId = M.UserId) AS A
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT M.UserId, A.TotalSessionCheckInTimeMinutes, DATEPART(WEEKDAY, M.EventTimestamp) FROM Mytable M
     CROSS APPLY (
       SELECT CAST((M1.EventTimestamp - M2.EventTimestamp) AS TIME) AS TotalSessionCheckInTimeMinutes
       FROM Mytable M1
          CROSS JOIN Mytable M2
            WHERE M1.Event = 'LogOut' AND M2.Event = 'CheckIn' AND M1.UserId = M.UserId) AS A
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to give the right data as it gives me a date in TotalSessionCheckInTimeMinutes in the year 1899 and the wrong week number.

Comment: I think problems in my code here: `M1.EventTimestamp - M2.EventTimestamp`. You can use convert or cast. :)

Comment: Thanks - I think you are close but its saying 'Operand type clash: int is incompatible with time'

Comment: Here's the schema: 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
 [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Event] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
 [EventTimestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: You can reference answers in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176596/operand-type-clash-int-is-incompatible-with-date-the-insert-statement-conflicte)