# Updating a date record and getting: Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm just trying to update a date and time record in my database. but it keeps giving me an error:

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

all I am doing is:

```
DECLARE @todayDate DATE =  GETDATE();
UPDATE Table SET UpdateDate =  @todayDate; -- UpdateDate is DATE
```

I've tried many things I'm seeing online.

```
UPDATE Table SET UpdateDate =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @todayDate); -- doesn't work.
```

I'm not using dateadd, just want to insert a date into a date field.

even the overkill of:

```
DECLARE @todayDate VARCHAR(50)=  CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),GETDATE());
UPDATE Table SET UpdateDate =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),todayDate )
```

doesnt work. It still returns:

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Comment: Why are you trying to store a *string* into a date field?

Comment: @Panagiotis - Many users suggested this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176596/operand-type-clash-int-is-incompatible-with-date-the-insert-statement-conflic

Comment: Many users don't know to use the *correct* type. That's why there are so many questions about conversion errors in SO. Again, why are you using strings? What is the type of `UdpateDate`? What's wrong with `UPDATE Table SET UpdateDate =  @todayDate; ` ?

Comment: BTW the question you link to expalins what's wrong with your query as well. You converted your date to a localized string that uses `-` as the date separator. Then you tried to convert that *implicitly* to a date, even though integers take precedence. So you ended up trying to save `2017 - 10 - 18`, ie 1990 into a date field

Comment: If `UpdateDate` is a `date` you shouldn't have any problems. If it's a `dateteime` but you want to save a `date` there, again you shouldn't have problems since you *already* stored `GETDATE()` into a `date` variable.

Comment: Again, why are you using strings? "This [Date] expression 12-4-2005 is a calculated int and the value is -1997. You should do like this instead '2005-04-12' with the ' (as string) . What is the type of UdpateDate? 'above i mentioned  '-- UpdateDate is DATE' type. What's wrong with UPDATE Table SET UpdateDate = @todayDate; Above i mention it returns: Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Comment: No it doesn't. The only things that would do so are the attempts to covnert to varchar. Post a *reproducible* example - the table creation statement and the update command. I suscpect though that you still try to store strings.

Comment: Post the `CREATE TABLE` for the table you are trying to update. Looks like `UpdateDate`  is an `int`

Comment: @MartinSmith - you were right. that field was incorrectly set as int instead of date. :(. You might want to put that as the answer to gain some points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE ( UpdateDate INT );
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (1);

DECLARE @todayDate DATE =  GETDATE();
UPDATE @Table SET UpdateDate =  CONVERT (INT, CONVERT (VARCHAR(10) , @todayDate, 112));
OUTPUT Deleted.*, Inserted.*;
```

PS: by the way you should change the updateDate-Field to proper Type DATE...